# Failed to customize a local key-binding in GDB mode in GNU Emacs 23

Tags: emacs, customization, key-bindings

I've added the code below to my `.emacs` to bind the command `gdb-restore-windows` to the key sequence <kbd>C-c C-.</kbd>. But when I start GDB mode and type the key sequence, I always get the prompt

> C-c C-. is undefined.

```lisp
(defun xyt/gdb-hotkey-hook ()
  (local-set-key (kbd "C-cC-.") 'gdb-restore-windows))

(add-hook 'gdb-mode-hook 'xyt/gdb-hotkey-hook)
```

Comment: You missed space: `(kbd "C-c C-.")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @artscan pointed out in the questions' comment, I had missing a space.